# No funciona el evento event.PreentDefault

Tags: javascript

tengo un formulario para dar de alta un cliente desde venta. La acción que debería realizarse es; que al hacer click en el botón del nuevo cliente se me habiliten los demás campos.
El evento no responde a ninguna accion.
Aquí tengo la parte donde le asigno el botón:

```
<div class="action_persona">

                    <h4>Datos de la Persona</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="btn_new btn_persona_venta"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Nueva Persona</a>

                </div>
```

Aqui tengo el codigo de la función del evento, el cual no responde:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            //Activa campos para registrar personas
              $('.btn_new_persona').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#nom_persona').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#tel_persona').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#dir_persona').removeAttr('disabled');
                

                $('#div_registro_persona').slideDown();
              });

        });
```

Comment: Es un error de sintaxis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta mal tu selector `$('.btn_new_persona')`

Bien puedes acceder a tu elemento de la siguiente manera:

```
$('.btn_new')
```

O de la siguiente:

```
$('.btn_persona_venta')
```

Es por eso que no te está realizando ninguna acción el evento.

Comment: Excelente millones de gracias